# How to use is.numeric or class in a for loop and if statement

Tags: r, loops

I'm new to R and trying to create a For loop running through each column of a survey that will test the type of column (factor or numeric) and will process each in a different fashion (means and stats for numeric and a bar chart for factor).

I've been stymied right off the bat by the what appears to be an inablity to get a true or false value using is.numeric or is.factor in reference to the column. I've also tried class tests. Below is what I get using the iris built in data set.

```
# the following tests won't work with numeric column refernce
# but does work for name column references
data("iris")
is.factor(iris$Species) # TRUE   
is.factor(iris[5])      # [5] is same column, should be T but gives F
class(iris$Species)     # "factor"
class(iris[5])          # "data.frame" Not "factor" as expected
```

Following is the type of loop with a test that I'm trying to get to work properly.

```
data("iris")
c=ncol(iris)

for (i in 1:c) 
{ 
if (class(iris[i])=='numeric') {print(mean(iris[i]))}
else {print('not numeric')}
}
                       #or
for (i in 1:c) 
{ 
if (is.numeric(iris[i])==TRUE) {print(mean(iris[i]))}
else {print('not numeric')}
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try `class(iris[,5])`

Comment: In your case iris$Species is a Vector while iris[5] is a subset of a data.frame hence "data.frame" not factor.
Instead, you should use doublle square brackets:  is.factor(iris[[5]]) == TRUE

Comment: Thank you!  I knew there had to be a simple solution!

Comment: I now also see that a comma before the column number would also work: is.factor(iris[,5])